# Is there an easy way to declare multiple sympy functions?

Tags: sympy

In Sympy, one can declare multiple symbols in one line using:

```
import sympy as sym
x,y,t = sym.symbols('x y t')
```

Is there a way to declare multiple functions in one line? The only way I see to declare them is line by line, using, for example:

```
x = sym.Function('x')(t)
y = sym.Function('y')(t)
```

Comment: It won't have all the string parsing abilities of `symbols`, but for a simple naming, a list comprehension works fine: `[Function(i) for i in 'A B C'.split()]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
>>> var('a b c', cls=Function)  # inject functions into namespace so now a(1) works
>>> a(1)
a(1)
>>> f = symbols('a b c', cls=Function); f[0](1)  # capture with variable(s) like f
a(1)
>>> A,B,C = symbols('a b c', cls=Function); A(1)  # or any three variables
a(1)
```

If you happen to want to create functions and assign them a generic argument (like `t`) you can use

```py
>>> from sympy.physics.vector import dynamicsymbols
>>> dynamicsymbols('a:c')
[a(t), b(t), c(t)]
>>> from sympy import Tuple
>>> fx,gx = Tuple(*dynamicsymbols('f g')).subs(t, x); fx
f(x)
>>> f1x,g1x = Tuple(*dynamicsymbols('f g', level=1)).subs(t, x); f1x
Derivative(f(x), x)
```

Comment: Nice. Is there a way to assign the argument variable like we do in `a = Function('a')(t)`?

Comment: see updated answer